# Calculate Energy Used on Server

Tags: php

Can I use PHP to calculate the energy used on a server I don't have immediate access to?

Comment: I doubt it without third party software.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a USB Uninteruptible Power System, you may be able to query it from time to time to find the actual load on the UPS (in Volt-Amperes or Watts) Do this over time, e.g. take an average over an hour at 5 minute intervals, and you can get a measure that you can convert to kWh.

How from within PHP? You'll either need to develop an external call to the UPS daemon or something else, and then scrape the information from that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an external sensor there.

So probably not.

Look at the [tweet-a-watt](http://www.ladyada.net/make/tweetawatt/) if you can get a kill-a-watt unit.